# Error: Compile Error: line 5:31 no viable alternative at character '' at line 5 column 31

Tags: apex, trigger

```
trigger CapitalizeName on Contact( before insert , before update)
{
    for(Contact c : Trigger.new)
        {
            if(c.FirstName ﻿!= null){

                c.FirstName = c.FirstName.subString(0 ,1).ToUpperCase() +  ﻿c.FirstName.subString(1);
                c.LastName =  c.LastName.subString(0 ,1).ToUpperCase() +  ﻿c.LastName.subString(1);

                }  
        }
}
```

I keep getting error with this very basic trigger and I don't understand why, help?

Comment: Did you copy-paste this trigger from elsewhere? Try typing it out yourself. Seems like it might be a hidden character.

Comment: Yes, typed it out in the live code editor it worked. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a few zero-width space characters, which was exposed when I copy-pasted this into my notepad program in ANSI mode:

```
trigger CapitalizeName on Contact( before insert , before update)
{
    for(Contact c : Trigger.new)
        {
            if(c.FirstName ?!= null){

                c.FirstName = c.FirstName.subString(0 ,1).ToUpperCase() +  ?c.FirstName.subString(1);
                c.LastName =  c.LastName.subString(0 ,1).ToUpperCase() +  ?c.LastName.subString(1);

                }  
        }
}
```

The ? characters are hidden zero-width characters that ended up in your code. Make sure you're not using some sort of fancy editor that likes to insert no-break-spaces or zero-width-spaces.